# complex data requirement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is my query:

```
select Views.VisitorID,
       Views.ViewID,
       Views.ViewDateTime,
       Views.VisitDate,
       Visits.Views,
       ProductID.Product,
       PageID.Page,
       hostID.host
from   Views
       left join Product
         on Views.ViewID = Product.ViewID
       left join ProductID
         on Product.ProductID = ProductID.ProductID
       left join host
         on Views.ViewID = host.ViewID
       left join hostID
         on host.hostID = hostID.hostID
       inner join PageID
         on Views.PageID = PageID.PageID
       inner join Visits
         on Views.VisitID = Visits.VisitID
where  Visits.Views <= 50
       and visits.firstvisit = 1
       and visitdate = '07 March, 2011'
       and ProductID.Product in ( 'product a', 'product b' )
group  by Views.VisitorID,
          Views.ViewID,
          Views.ViewDateTime,
          Views.VisitDate,
          Visits.Views,
          ProductID.Product,
          PageID.Page,
          hostID.host
order  by Views.VisitorID,Views.ViewID, Views.ViewDateTime
```

I am looking for the above records for every visitorID when the very first viewID (there are multiple viewID for each visitorID) is either 'product a' or 'product b'. Can someone help?

Appended below is the data and the expected results are visitorid=1, 2 & 7.

```
VisitorID        ViewID                ViewDateTime        VisitDate        Views     Product    Page   host  
1                5874194128        1/31/2011 0:00        31-Jan                1        A        X        Y  
2                5874194131        1/31/2011 0:00        31-Jan                6        B        X        Y  
2                5874209907        1/31/2011 0:08        31-Jan                6        B        X        Y  
2                5874210697        1/31/2011 0:08        31-Jan                6        B        X        Y  
2                5874213486        1/31/2011 0:10        31-Jan                6        B        X        Y  
2                5874220373        1/31/2011 0:13        31-Jan                6        D        X        Y  
2                5874223494        1/31/2011 0:14        31-Jan                6        D        X        Y  
3                5874194139        1/31/2011 0:00        31-Jan                2        E        X        Y  
3                5874227680        1/31/2011 0:16        31-Jan                2        A        X        Y  
4                5874194149        1/31/2011 0:00        31-Jan                1        F        X        Y  
4                6082113181        2/22/2011 4:39        22-Feb                1        B        X        Y  
5                5874194150        1/31/2011 0:00        31-Jan                1        F        X        Y  
5                5909359616        2/3/2011 8:35          3-Feb                1        A        X        Y  
5                6042085229        2/17/2011 23:59       17-Feb                2        A        X        Y  
5                6042086534        2/17/2011 23:59       17-Feb                2        A        X        Y  
6                5874194154        1/31/2011 0:00        31-Jan                1        D        X        Y  
6                5936833964        2/6/2011 2:37          6-Feb                1        A        X        Y  
6                5959528921        2/9/2011 0:33          9-Feb                1        B        X        Y  
7                5874194157        1/31/2011 0:00        31-Jan                1        A        X        Y  
7                5937521299        2/6/2011 20:58         6-Feb                4        C        X        Y  
7                5937542326        2/6/2011 21:20         6-Feb                4        C        X        Y  
7                5937542560        2/6/2011 21:20         6-Feb                4        C        X        Y  
7                5937552378        2/6/2011 21:31         6-Feb                4        C        X        Y
```

Comment: Can you please provide sample data? Or at least name the tables & columns appropriately?

Comment: That isn't your query, as it's missing all sorts of punctuation. Also, it's very hard to follow with `Table1`, `Table2` and columns named `a`, `b`, and so forth. At least take the time to post something close to a real query that will actually execute if you want help.

Comment: Also you need to define what "first" means (as ordered by what?). I suggest distilling the problem down to an example scenario with a couple of tables.

Comment: edited to reflect tables and columns. It is ordered by datetime.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output. Your question is still very vague (although much better with actual table and column names). SQL tables have no concept of 'first viewID' unless you define what you consider 'first', and there's a way to find that one. For instance, if there's a viewID and a creation date, you can use `Min(creationDate)` to decide which is 'first'.

Comment: added sample data and expected results.

Comment: thanks Martin for fixing my data; can you please tell me how you did it?

Comment: the solution that I am looking for is in t-sql. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

V2 - is the minimum/first view for each visitor on that day.
V3 - is the visitors which looked at product A or B on their first view.
Then the rest of the query takes those visitors and links them to the rest of the data.

```
Select V.VisitorID,
   V.ViewID,
   V.ViewDateTime,
   V.VisitDate,
   VS.Views,
   PID.Product,
   PGID.Page,
   HID.host
from Views V
inner join (
    Select V2.VisitorID, V2.VisitDate
    from (
        select VisitorID, VisitDate, Min(ViewID) as FirstViewID
        from Views
        where visitdate = '07 March, 2011'
        group by VisitorID, VisitDate
    ) V2 on V.VisitorID = V2.VisitorID and V.ViewID = V2.FirstViewID
    inner join Product P on V.ViewID = P.ViewID
    inner join ProductID PID on P.ProductID = PID.ProductID
    where PID.Product in ('A', 'B')
) V3 on V3.VisitorID = V.VisitorID and V3.VisitDate = V.VisitDate
inner join Product P on V.ViewID = P.ViewID
inner join ProductID PID on P.ProductID = PID.ProductID
inner join Host H on V.ViewID = H.ViewID
inner join HostID HID on H.hostID = HID.hostID
inner join PageID PGID on V.PageID = PGID.PageID
inner join Visits VS on V.VisitID = VS.VisitID
where VS.Views <= 50
   and VS.firstvisit = 1
```

Comment: the subquery table is not identified. T1 from the where clause does not have the product information. There are 7 tables in my original query: Views, Visits, ProductID, Product, PageID, host and hostID. Nevertheless, thanks.

Comment: I don't really understand your database but based on what you have posetd it is returning the visitorID appropriate to your data from your data.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not working. It is only pulling the min(ViewID). If you look at my sample data, once the condition has been met i.e. min(ViewID) where Product is either A or B, it should also pulls all other ViewIDs subsequent to (minViewID).

Comment: so let me get this straight. You want the results to be exactly what you have list except with visitor who did not look at a or b first filtered out?